# Guidance needed-Navbar question (clear:both and display:table)

Tags: html, css, css-float, navbar, display

I'm confused in this specific part of code. If anyone could explain to me, it'd be greatly appreciated!!
I'm making a navbar and it looks like this:

[image]

This is part of the CSS I'm confused about:

```
    img{
      weight:100px;
      height:100px;
      border-radius: 100%;
    }
    body{
      margin:0;
    }
    header{
      background-color: lightblue;
    }
    
/*don't really understand this part*/
    header::after{
      content:" ";
      display:table;
      clear:both;
    }
    .container{
      width:80%;
      margin:0 auto;
    }
    .logo{
      float:left;
      padding:5px 0;
    }
    nav{
      float:right;
    }

    nav ul{
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
    list-style: none; /*remove HTML bullets*/
    }
    nav li{
      display:inline-block;
      margin:0 25px;
      padding-top:55px;
      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;

    }
    nav a{
      color:#444;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    nav a:hover{
      color:black;
    }


<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My logo</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <!--a navbar should be in header section becuase it's not the content-->
        <header>
          <div class="container">
            <img class="logo" src="logo.jpg" alt="">
            <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Product</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>

        </header>


      </body>
    </html>
```

`header::after{content:" "; display:table; clear:both; }`

So my question is the background color in the pic would disappear without this part of code and I don't understand why, esp the display:table and clear:both. I do have logo and the li part float on both sides and clear:both doesn't stop them from floating and the background color would still show. I'm confused as why it's there and how display and clear both would affect the background color. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have floated all the content of header. This is like giving them all an absolute position and removes them from the flow of their parent which means the parent container, with no other content, will act as if it is empty. You could also give the header a height to see the background color, however, that might make it harder to adjust based on the content wrapping.

The CSS in question adds some content via the ::after's content prop. Then you clear the floats to make the content be seen by header, which is technically it's parent. The display table could be display block as well. It just makes sure that the after acts like an element would if it were placed in the html. But instead you are faking it with CSS.